# Is it grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatically agreeing to construct the a sentence using the word cheating as given below.

> He has committed cheating on her.

Comment: I would certainly reject this usage. But strange...very strange that *'committed cheating'* is used at many places! I learned this today.

Comment: @P.E.Dant any reason to roll it back?

Comment: @MaulikV No, but _committed_ is never used with _cheating_ in a sentence like this by a native speaker. And I mean never. We never _commit cheating_, and never use the expression. Ever.

Comment: I agree with P.E. Dant. to commit cheating is not right, ever. Googling stuff is not proof of anything. That is a lesson many have yet to learn.

Comment: The correct form is: He cheated on her.

Answer (score -1):

to commit(v.) a sin/crime (n.)

You can use commit (verb) in this form, using a noun (crime, etc.).

Cheating is not a noun. So may be able to write "commit cheat (as a sin) or commit a cheat" **BUT** it's not used anywhere as far as I know.

[check this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1018751100990)

"Cheating" suffice in that sentence to make your point.

Plus, I have not seen people use "Commit" with an *informal* verb, it is mostly used when talking about *formal crimes*.

Comment: He cheated on  her. He cheated on the test. No commit.

Comment: @Lambie yes as I mentioned, we "can't" use them. I know the phrase "he cheated", just trying to convince her/him to see what is actually happening.

Comment: @Lambie "test cheating" is one word, like he commit "test-cheating", and I've seen such thing on the net today on an English website, that's why I wrote it.

Comment: Yet you failed to give the basic idea: to cheat on a test, to cheat on a spouse. It's missing in your answer. :) Also, to commit test cheating is wrong. Period. :)

Comment: @Lambie I guess he knows how to use "cheating" for it's so common and he can search the net and find it, he just wanna know if the other one (commit+cheating) is correct or not, which I said it's not.

Comment: You told him that he can use commit test cheating. That is wrong. What he obviously does not know is how to say: to cheat on a test, to cheat on a spouse. Otherwise, he would not have asked the question.

Comment: @Lambie I saw this (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1018751100990) I thought it was correct...

Comment: It should read: the decision to cheat on tests. It's poorly said in that academic article.